# how to get image from a module

Tags: magento2, module, url

in my case there is a picture inside my module and I want to get that image inside an HTML file (it's an html file for email header), but when I use Magento syntax it doesn't appear, I have got the page blank without the alt attribute displayed, that means it is there but the page still blank

I have tested with a simple link **src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg"** it works

but not with this :

```
src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendorname_Core::images/pic.png'); ?>"
```

can anyone help me, please?

update:

my file inside app/design dir  to override : vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/header.html:

```
<table class="wrapper" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td class="wrapper-inner" align="center">
            <table class="main" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="header">
                        <img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Mymodule_Email::images/logo.png'); ?>"
                        />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="main-content">
                        <!-- Begin Content -->
```

Comment: make sure you have entered the right path, in above case pic.jpg will be in pub/static/.../Vendorname_Core/pic.png, make to add `img` directory name if you have putted in sub dir.

Comment: i have updated the question , even i put it inside a dir it doesn't work , is there any difference to put it in adminhtml area or frontend?

Comment: I suggest you to echo that URL directly and check for the proper path and correct it accordingly

Comment: see the update now ! @RizwanKhan

Comment: you are writing php code in html file. it will never work.

Comment: @RakeshVarma There is a solution to call the image from the module with another way ?

Comment: if you want to set the email header logo then you can upload it from the admin as well. No need to override a template file

Comment: i need to do it by code because there is many  deployment instances, so i want to make changes over all instances

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way ..

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendorname_Core::images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

and image directory like :

> Vendorname/Core/view/frontend/web/images/image.png

then run below commands

```
rm -rf var/di/* generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/* pub/static/*

php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

After check your image showing

Comment: it doesn't work bro for me even if i do that , and the same files structure

Comment: @lovecoding you want to call in phtml file where? and write here phtml file also in question

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a file inside the web folder of your module

You can refer below example.

Ex. file placed in below path

`app/code/Vendorname/Core/view/frontend/web/images/pic.png`

Then you can use the

```php
$this->getViewFileUrl('Vendorname_Core::images/pic.png')
```

if not still not load then you can verify that images is deployed in the pub/static with the same path of your module if it does not then  then please run the below command

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: yes it's loaded inside pub/static with the same path , i don't know why it won't be displayed on the mail , the mail still without header image